# "Import Error: No module named urls" with Django 1.8 and Rest Framework 3.7

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I'm using django==1.8, rest_framework=3.7.7, python==2.7.12

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns += [
     url(r'^api/core/', include('core.urls')),
]
```

**core/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^/users/', core_view.userlist),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
queryset = User.objects.all()
serializer_class = UserSerializer
userlist = UserList.as_view()
```

When I'm navagating to: http://localhost:8000/api/core/users I'm getting the following error:

```
ImportError at /api/core/users
No module named urls
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/api/core/users
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named urls
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/compat.py in <module>, line 26
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.12
```

what is wrong in configuration?

Comment: As @Alasdair mentioned, what version of django rest framework are you using?

Comment: djangorestframework==3.7.7

Comment: if you check the release notes for 3.7 in the link @Alaisdair supplied - "Updated test matrix to add Django 2.0 and drop Django 1.8 & 1.9 BC Change: This removes Django 1.8 and Django 1.9 from Django REST Framework supported versions."

Comment: `Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/compat.py`

Comment: what should i do now. I can't change django version?, need to install rest-framework<3.x?

Comment: @AKS please see my answer from 20 minutes ago: "You should install an earlier version of rest framework, or upgrade Django"

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn’t have the leading slash in `r'^/users/'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django Rest Framework dropped support for Django 1.8 [in version 3.7](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/release-notes/#370).

You should install an earlier version of rest framework, or upgrade Django (note that Django 1.8 reaches end-of-life in April 2018)

Comment: @GalSilberman because it's mentioned in the `Exception location`

Comment: @Alasdair thanks i installed DRF with version 2.4.8 and it worked. it was compatibility issue

Comment: Glad that worked. You've picked a very old version to install. Since support is dropped in 3.7, I would have thought that [3.6.4](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/release-notes/#364) would be the obvious choice to install.

Answer (score -1):

Just Make sure you include `core` app in your `INSTALLED_APPS` settings, and that you have init.py in your core directory folder.

Look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urls/) for more information.

Comment: yes i have added it in INSTALLED_APPS and it contains the init.py