# from django.urls import ( # noqa ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.urls'

Tags: django, django-urls

I am getting error "No module named 'django.urls'" in django 1.9

The problem is with urls.py in the application

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

from accounts.views import (login_view, register_view, logout_view)

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^', include("posts.urls", namespace='posts')),
    url(r'^api/posts/', include("posts.api.urls", namespace='posts-api')),
    ...
]
```

The only url code specified below causes error. After commenting this line of code, django server runs fine.

```
url(r'^api/posts/', include("posts.api.urls", namespace='posts-api')),
```

Made some changed in the import statement

```
from posts.api import urls as urls_api
```

and in the urlpatterns content still error persists.

```
url(r'^api/posts/', include("urls_api", namespace='posts-api')),
```

**posts/urls.py**

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from django.contrib import admin

    from .views import (
        post_list,
        post_create,
        post_detail,
        post_update,
        post_delete,
        )

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', post_list, name='list'),
        url(r'^create/$', post_create),
        url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_detail, name='detail'),
        url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', post_update, name='update'),
        url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/delete/$', post_delete),
    ]
```

**posts/api/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from .views import (
    PostListAPIView
    )

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', PostListAPIView.as_view(), name='list'),
]
```

Comment: Show code in module `posts.api.urls`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Import Error: No module named urls" with Django 1.8 and Rest Framework 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49486374/import-error-no-module-named-urls-with-django-1-8-and-rest-framework-3-7)